# Хранение секретных ключей в Android

Tags: android, безопасность, криптография

Задача: приложение должно хранить секретный ключ (строка), безопасно, без возможности извлечения через декомпиляцию приложения или рут.

Известно: в андроид есть три встроенных механизма для хранения секретных данных. KeyStore, KeyChain и Android KeyStore Provider:

- KeyStore наименее безопасен (так как с помощью рута можно заполучить доступ непосредственно к файлу с зашифрованными данными)
- KeyChain более удобен для использования секретных данных между приложениями (запрашивает у пользователя разрешение с помощью системного диалога)
- Android KeyStore Provider вроде как наиболее подходит под задачу.

Вопросы:

1. Каким образом Android KeyStore Provider защищен от декомпиляции приложения?
2. Можем ли мы избежать уничтожения информации при смене или отключения пароля к устройству? Android 6.0 и выше.
3. Каким образом Android KeyStore Provider защищен на рутованных устройствах? Вроде бы на некоторых устройствах под хранение таких данных выделяется некое hardware-protected хранилище, куда доступ закрыт даже с root. Но что это за устройства? Как много их? И что происходит на остальных устройствах с рутом - эти данные просто лежат в какой-то директории?

Answer (score 7):

Это все один и тот же механизм. `KeyStoreProvider` - это провайдер (реализация) механизма `KeyStore`, а `KeyChain` некое верхнеуровневое API доступа к `KeyStore` - нечто вроде менеджера.

То есть для создания `KeyStore` вы должны выбрать одного из провайдеров. Список провайдеров можно получить через `Security.getProviders()` и далее выбрать `KeyStore.getInstance(provider)`

Теперь ближе к сути вопроса. Вопрос защищенности `KeyStore` зависит от его реализации, защищенность можно проверить - как говорит документация:

> Key material may be bound to the secure hardware (e.g., Trusted Execution Environment (TEE), Secure Element (SE)) of the Android device. When this feature is enabled for a key, its key material is never exposed outside of secure hardware. If the Android OS is compromised or an attacker can read the device's internal storage, the attacker may be able to use any app's Android Keystore keys on the Android device, but not extract them from the device. This feature is enabled only if the device's secure hardware supports the particular combination of key algorithm, block modes, padding schemes, and digests with which the key is authorized to be used. To check whether the feature is enabled for a key, obtain a KeyInfo for the key and inspect the return value of KeyInfo.isInsideSecurityHardware().

грубо говоря, это означает, что если ключи находятся в аппаратно защищенном месте то все типа "ок", если иначе - то через рут можно все раскурочить.

Для Samsung'ов таковым является механизм [Knox](https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/knox-android), при получении рута (только рута без перепрошивки) он остается защищенным, хотя перепрошивка сбрасывает защиту Knox'а

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно ли как-то избежать сброса информации при смене пароля к устройству? Как я понимаю, шифр к хранилищу зависит от этого пароля и как раз этим обеспечивается защита от декомпиляции приложения (в приложении не хранится никакого пароля для получения ключей, его выдает система). С другой стороны, получается, что  даже на самсунге с кнокс и рутом злоумышленник все равно может пропатчить приложение, чтобы оно вывело ему дешифрованные данные. Верно?

Comment: Я думаю вы немножко неверно понимаете как работает Knox, почитайте [эту статью на Хабре](https://habr.com/company/yandex/blog/344382/)

Comment: Knox дополнительно к этому контролирует доступ к ключу и если доступ не авторизованный, то он тупо блокирует содержимое `KeyStore`, то есть получение рута с последующим доступом к ключу вообще то приведет блокировке содержимого на аппаратном уровне

Comment: Да, скорее всего действительно не понимаю. Но общий смысл шифрования в статье сводится к тому, что сам по себе мастер-пароль нигде не хранится, а хэш сгенерированный на его основе используется для создания пары ключей по принципу ассимитричного шифрования, которая в свою очередь используется для создания ключа, с которым шифруются данные.Плюс система восстановления построенная на основе шифрования одного из промежуточных ключей выше. Но как это связано с Knox? Опять же насколько я знаю hardware-protected хранилища есть и на устройствах без Knox... Буду благодарен, если объясните где я не прав.

Comment: А если злоумышленник не будет пытаться получить доступ к ключу как таковому? Допустим, на устройстве установлено приложение которое в ходе работы получает секретную строку из KeyStore. Злоумышленнику будет достаточно пересобрать приложение с тем же сертификатом (насколько я знаю, реверс-инжиринг андроид-приложение позволяет это сделать), добавив в это место код вывода уже полученной секретной строки в UI (например, AlertDIalog).

Comment: Причем тут сертификат? `KeyStore` (Knox лишь его одна из реализаций) использует в качестве мастер пароля данные аутентификации пользователя: pin, отпечаток или паттерн экрана. При этом ни пин, ни пароль нигде не хранятся - хранится хэш и отдельно соль

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79376/discussion-between-bartwell-and-barmaley).